# Ubuntu 11.10 LAMP is very slow

Tags: 11.10, php, lamp, wordpress

My lamp stack on a local machine is too slow.
I have successfully installed wordpress but any request (e.g login,add new post) is too slow.
How can i resolve what's wrong ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Chech this out. It's very useful [Tuning LAMP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tune-lamp-2/)

Especially chapater ->Resource related settings in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS configuration.  If you have invalid DNS servers configured or a networking problem is obstructing your machine from reaching your DNS server, you may experience long delays.